# Proof of Hilbert Projection Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If M is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space H and $x \in H$, then:

There exists a unique element $\hat{x} \in M$ such that:

$\|x-\hat{x} \|=\inf_{y \in M}\|x-y \|$

To proof of the existence of such a point (the uniqueness is proven separately) is given as:

Proof of existence of $\hat{x} \in M$

If $d=\inf_{y \in M} \|x-y \|^2$ then there is a sequence $\{y_n \}$ of elements of  M such that $\|y_n-x \|^2\rightarrow d$. Apply the parallelogram law and using the fact that $(y_m +y_n)/2 \in M$ we can write

$0 \leq \|y_m-y_n \|^2=-4\|(y_m+y_n)/2-x \|^2 + 2(\|y_n-x \|^2+ \|y_m-x\|^2)$
$ \leq -4d + 2(\|y_n-x \|^2+ \|y_m-x\|^2)$  $\rightarrow 0$ as $m,n \rightarrow \infty$

The first term on the second line seems fairly clear:

If $y_n=y_m$ then you have an equality so that $=-4\|(y_m+y_n)/2-x \|^2= -4d$.

If $y_n \neq y_m$ then the negative sign means that the inequality holds i.e. $=-4\|(y_m+y_n)/2-x \|^2 < -4d$. As $y_m$ must be further from x than $y_n$.

The second term (which is unchanged) is causing me some confusion.

Again if $y_n=y_m$ then you have an equality so that $2(\|y_n-x \|^2+ \|y_m-x\|^2)=4d$. This then means that the expression sums to zero and so in this case there is no problem.

However
If $y_n \neq y_m$ then the second term $\|y_m-x\|^2> d$. Indeed it can be arbitrarily large?

I can see that the expression only works if $y_m=y_n$ but surely this is a proof
that the point is unique not that is exists?

Can someone please explain how this is a proof of the existence of such an element?

I mean the existence of such an element is assumed as we are told that there is a sequence $\{y_n \}$ of elements of  M such that $\|y_n-x \|^2\rightarrow d$. But I don't see how the expression above contradicts this? If $y_m \neq y_n$ then the expression above could be arbitrarily large whether or not $\|y_n-x \|^2\rightarrow d$? So there is no contradiction that I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\|y_n -x\|^2 \to d$, for all $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ s.t.
$$\|y_n - x\|^2 \leq d + \epsilon$$
for all $n \geq N$.

This means the last equation satisfies 
$$-4d + 2(\|y_n-x \|^2+ \|y_m-x\|^2) \leq -4d + 2\left((d + \epsilon) + (d + \epsilon)\right) = 4\epsilon$$
for all $m,n \geq N$.

So the limit does go to zero.

Comment: I agree that the epxression works if $y_n$ and $y_m$ converge to the same value, but even in this case how does that prove that $y_n$ such that $\|y_n-x \|^2\rightarrow d$ exists? Also why would $y_m$ and $y_n$ converge to the same value?

Comment: @Bazman   You started your proof with this: "If $d=\inf_{y \in M} \|x-y \|^2$ then there is a sequence $\{y_n \}$ of elements of  M such that $\|y_n-x \|^2\rightarrow d$."  By definition, $d$ is the infimum of an infinite sequence of points $y_n$ s.t. ||y_n - x|| \to d$.  They converge to the same value by definition.

Comment: Ok that was the part I did not understand. The proof logic still seems kinda circular though?

Comment: Sorry still a little confused  if y_n if the infinium then surely any other sequence y_m will be less than y_n and therefore the distance will be greater?

Comment: Seems ok to me.  You start off by supposing there is a finite distance $d$ with a bunch of points $y_n$ in the subspace getting closer and closer and to that distance from $x$.  Then you show that in fact that implies they need to get closer to each other.  Then since the subspace is closed, $y_n$ must be getting close to a point in the subspace.

Comment: I agree with everything you say regarding $y_n$ but what happens if $y_m \neq y_n$? If you say they have to be the same then I really find the proof pretty circular, if they are different seems to me the proof doesn't work?

Comment: This is going beyond what I signed up to answer.  Maybe someone else can help you finish it off.

Comment: OK thanks for your help to this point.